# how to combine matplotlib figures after they are saved?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I know that the ideal solution would be to plot them in multiple axes by calling `plt.subplots(nrows=x, ncols=y)` but the code where I am plotting was already structured in a way which would make it very hard for me to convert to plotting in the same context like that...

So that being said, I have a folder with 5 saved `.pdf` images that were created in matplotlib. Is there a way I can open these up and save them in the same file while maintaining the `.pdf` filetype (i.e. not converting them to `.png`s in some image editing program)?

Comment: You can search with keywords `pickle dump/load` of matplotlib plots.